# Computing large combinations

Tags: c++, algorithm, permutation, dynamic-programming, combinatorics

How would you compute a combination such as (100,000 choose 50,000)?

I have tried three different approaches thus far but for obvious reasons each has failed:

1) Dynamic Programming- The size of the array just gets to be so ridiculous it seg faults

```
unsigned long long int grid[p+1][q+1];

//Initialise x boundary conditions
for (long int i = 0; i < q; ++i) {
  grid[p][i] = 1;
}

//Initialise y boundary conditions
for (long int i = 0; i < p; ++i) {
  grid[i][q] = 1;
}


for (long int i = p - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
  for (long int j = q - 1; j >= 0; --j) {
     grid[i][j] = grid[i+1][j] + grid[i][j+1];
   }
}
```

2) Brute Force - Obviously calculating even 100! isn't realistic

```
unsigned long long int factorial(long int n)
{
  return (n == 1 || n == 0) ? 1 : factorial(n - 1) * n;
}
```

3) Multiplicative Formula- I'm unable to store the values they are just so large

```
const int gridSize = 100000; //say 100,000
unsigned long long int paths = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {
    paths *= (2 * gridSize) - i;
    paths /= i + 1;
}

// code from (http://www.mathblog.dk/project-euler-15/)
```

If it helps for context the aim of this is to solve the "How many routes are there through an m×n grid" problem for large inputs. Maybe I am miss-attacking the problem?

Answer (score 4):

C(100000, 50000) is a huge number with 30101 decimal digits: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=C%28100000%2C+50000%29

Obviously `unsigned long long` will not be enough to store it. You need some arbitrary large integers library, like GMP: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multiple_Precision_Arithmetic_Library

Otherwise, multiplicative formula should be good enough.

Answer (score 3):

"How would you compute ..." depends very much on the desired accuracy. Precise results can only be computed with arbitrary precission numbers (eg. GMP), but it is rather likely that you don't really need the exact result.

In that case I would use the Stirling Approximation for factorials ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation ) and calculate with doubles. The number of summands in the expansion can be used to regulate the error. The wikipedia page will also give you an error estimate.

Answer (score 1):

Here is recursive formula that might help : -

NCk = (N-1)C(k-1)*N/K

Use a recursive call for (N-1)C(K-1) first then evaluate NCk on result.

As your numbers will be very large use one of following alternatives.

> 1. GMP
> 2. Use your own implementation where you can store numbers as sequence of binary bits in array and use booth's algorithm for multiplication
>      and shift & subtract for division.